# How to repeat commands like changing tabs `gt` in Vim without repeatedly retyping them over and over?

Tags: vim

When I want to change a tab I press `gt` and I am taken to the next tab.

However I have several such tabs and it gets really weird.

And `gt` is only an example, there are other situations when something to 
repeat one's command just by pressing one key, or holding one key instead pressing two or more keys would by handy.

Any idea how to do that in Vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to repeat commands?

Usually you can use a [count](https://vimhelp.org/intro.txt.html#count) to precede a Vim command to repeat it a certain number of times. For example, you can use `5j` to go down five lines, `4w` to go to the beginning of the fourth next word and `3dd` to delete three lines.

Even though the count is used most often as a repetition, that's not always the case, and the `gt` command is one example of exception, in which using a count makes Vim go to the Nth tab, so `3gt` will not skip tabs but go to the third tab. (For `gT` though, the count is used as a repeat, so `3gT` will go to the third previous tab.)

> Repeat one's command just by pressing one key.

For normal mode commands that modify the buffer, you can typically use the `.` command to repeat that last command, so that would qualify as pressing a single key. You can also use a count with `.`, so for instance you can use `5.` to repeat that modification five times.

That's not the case for `gt` though, since it's not a command that changes the current buffer.

You could [record a macro](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#recording), in which case you can repeat it with two presses of the *same* key.

For example, you could type `qtgtq` to record a "next tab" command into register "t", then `@t` to repeat that once, then `@@` to repeat it the next time (`@@` will execute the last used macro.) So assuming you find pressing `@@` more convenient than `gt`, that's a possibility.

Finally, if what you really want is to be able to change tabs using a single keystroke, that you can keep pressing quickly to cycle through tabs more quickly, then what you want is a mapping, to create a new keybinding.

For instance, if you want to use Control-T to change tabs, then use the following command:

```
:nnoremap <c-t> gt
```

This will allow you to switch to the next tab by pressing Control-T. And you can easily hold down the Control key while you press "T" repeatedly (or even hold it down for repetition from your keyboard driver.)

Just be aware that you might pick a key that was serving another function (Control-T jumps back through the tag stack), so you might want to take that into consideration.